# how to share a folder between WIN10 and ubuntu installed with VMWare 12?

Tags: vmware

How can I share a folder between WIN10,on which I installed VMware Workstation (12.1.0 Player for Windows)?

It is working well together, but useful to share documents in between 2 OS.

Thanks
Merry Xmas & Happy New Year
Serros

Comment: You can either use an NSF or Samba network share which may be difficult for you to setup, or you can mount a shared folder in your Ubuntu system

Comment: Thanks Charles,Am a newbie, how do you mount a shared folder in Ubuntu system?

Comment: It's a fairly complex process - I;ve been typing the answer, and just checking for errors right now.

Answer (score 1):

### Step-by-step instructions on how to share a Windows folder under Ubuntu 17.04

1. Under Windows create a shared folder, say *winshare*, and enable it in the VM config.
2. In the VM install open-vm-tools with `sudo apt install open-vm-tools`
3. Create a folder on your desktop with `mkdir ~/Desktop/share`
4. Add the following line to your *.bashrc*:

   mountpoint -q ~/Desktop/share || vmhgfs-fuse .host:/winshare ~/Desktop/share

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not installed the `vmtools` from the VMWare 'CD' for your Ubuntu guest, you will need to do so first.  Please note that `open-vm-tools` from the Ubuntu repositories does not currently support file sharing in Ubuntu.

Start your Ubuntu virtual machine, and in the VM window, choose  "VM->Install VMWare Tools".  This will mount the CD containing the VMWare tools on your virtual machine.  In your Ubuntu installation, use the file manager to extract the contents of `VMwareTools-10.0.5-3228253.tar.gz` from the CD to a directory on your Ubuntu installation.  The version of the .tar.gz file will change with VMWare versions.

Open a terminal window (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and navigate to the directory where you extracted the VMWare tools.  Enter the subdirectory "vmware-tools-distrib" and then enter the command `sudo ./vmware-install.pl`  using the default for all prompts that the program gives you.

---

Shutdown your virtual machine at this point

---

In your VMWare control window, edit the settings of the virtual machine.  Under 'Options->Shared Folders' you can add a directory from your host machine that you would like to be able to use on your guest machine.  Choose to 'Always enable' the use of shared folders.

In your Ubuntu machine you will find this folder located at `/mnt/hgfs/<name_you_specified`

[image]