# Share a folder on VMWare Ubuntu 14 to a host Windows10

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I've got a Win10 Host folder shared to my VMWare Ubuntu 14.04 after following this

[how to share a folder between WIN10 and ubuntu installed with VMWare 12?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713111/how-to-share-a-folder-between-win10-and-ubuntu-installed-with-vmware-12)

But how do I share the other way i.e. on my Win10 host I'd like to view/edit the contents of my Ubuntu folder /Home/Pictures

I'm running VMware Workstation 11.1.4 on my Win10 laptop

Comment: Do VMWare tools not help in this regards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to share host folders to the guest, and then have them mounted in the proper locations.  The inverse sharing method, from VM to Host, don't exist in the same way unless you set up a fileshare system that Microsoft would support (i.e a Samba share), and then mount it from the local IP on the VM (likely a local IP on your system only, or on your Bridged network, I don't know.).

Note that because this is a non-trivial process covered in other questions/answers and site guides, I don't go into detail here, however [there is a very good guide for this on the Ubuntu Help Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html)

The process for setting up such shares is... painful... though... so it's probably far easier to just install `openssh-server` on the VM, and then use FileZilla to connect over SFTP to the VM and then access the user's home directory and pull data off that way.  It's not a nice file share, mind you, but it's probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: I got it working with Samba using this, after I got my path correct at the 3rd attempt   https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html